# Getting negative value with bit-fields

Tags: c, struct, bit-fields

I have a question related to bit-fields in C. Here I have such a structure:

```
struct Register
{
  int bit:1;
};

int main(void)
{
  struct Register bit = {1};

  printf("\nbit = %d", bit.bit);
  return 0;
}
```

Can you please explain me why do I get:

> bit = -1

Comment: Read about 2's complement.

Comment: A signed bit can only store two values. When using 2's complement those values are :  `0` and `-1`.

Comment: @haccks So, if I understand correctly, 1, is represented as 01, so in 2's complement it's transformed to 11, so in decimal representation, it's -1. Yes ?

Comment: You only have 1 bit. In 2's complement the first bit is the sign bit. You simply cannot represent `+1` in 2's complement with a single bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're working with bitfields, you should use `unsigned int`. `signed int` is a problem for bit-fields.

Comment: Exactly, the compiler will internally insert bit shifts and masks for retrieving the bit values, in this case you probably get the equivalent of: 0x80000000>>31 which is 0xffffffff for signed but 0x1 for unsigned

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh Can I ask you one more question related to this ?

Comment: Thank you. For example, if I write bit = 12, then I get as result -4. How do I get this ?

Comment: @JohnG. see, a value of `12` is not able to fit in the specified bitfield-ed variable, right? It overflows, so the result you see is not worty of anything.

Answer (score 1):

use unsigned int , it stores 0 and 1,

```
struct Register
{
unsigned int bit:1;
};

int main(void)
{
 struct Register bit = {1};

 printf("\nbit = %d", bit.bit);
 return 0;
}
```