# Bit-field: Understanding how the following program works

Tags: c, bit-fields

Can you, please, explain me this case:

```
    struct REGISTRU
{
    int bit3:4;

};


struct REGISTRU bit={13};
printf("\n%d", bit.bit3);
```

Why is the result -3 ?

Comment: Did you not get the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30614367/2173917)?

Comment: @SouravGhosh You see, I understand that I should work with unsigned, but the actual question is something that's supposed to be at my exam, so I try to understand the case with int.

Comment: to put it out in very simple words, signed = sign bit + value, so for 4 bit signed bitfield variable, logically, (1 bit sign + 3 bit value) , and 3 bits cannot hold `13`, max 7.

Comment: Because two-complement the number 13 (1101 binary) is bigger then the max positive 4 bits (signed) integer. This max value is 7 decimal == 0111 binary! If you use `unsigned int` the result shall be 13! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to be very careful while using bit-fields.
As you declared variable as only **int**, in C it is default **signed int**.

If you see binary value of 13, it is 1101. So `MSB` is taken as sign value so you are getting -3. If you want it to take value as 13 use below code:

```
struct REGISTRU
{
   unsigned int bit3:4; 
};

void main()
{ 
  struct REGISTRU bit={13};
  printf("\n%d", bit.bit3);
}
```

Comment: Surely `printf("\n%u", bit.bit3);`?

Comment: Yeah it will print 13. Make sure that variable in `struct` is defined as `unsigned int`

Answer (score 0):

I creates a struct with a field called bit3 of type integer of 4-bit length (you can store values from 0 to 15).

```
struct REGISTRU
{
    int bit3:4;

};
```

Then creates a variable called bit of type REGISTRU and intitializes the value to 13.

```
struct REGISTRU bit={13};
```

Finally prints out the value

```
printf("\n%d", bit.bit3);
```

Comment: A signed 4-bit value can store `-8` to `+7` using 2's complement.

Comment: @SergioFormiggini, I didn't noticed that